# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread

Tags: ios, objective-c, foundation

I have a very strange crash in some KVO related code. My app crashes in NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread().

I have a NSURLSessionDataTask embedded in a NSOperation subclass, and I'm observing the state property of the task using KVO in order to update the state of my NSOperation (set it as finished when the task is completed).

I'm probably not going to be able to reproduce this easily as it only happens randomly on very rare occasions (this is only the third time I'm catching this in the debugger). I would still like to understand what is going on if someone already encountered something similar.
What I don't understand (judging by the stacktrace), is how my code could be responsible for something like this.

Here is the stacktrace (and I'm attaching 2 screenshots) :

```
Thread 24Queue : com.apple.NSURLSession-work (serial)
#0  0x38886626 in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x2ea28c3e in NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread ()
#2  0x2ea16e86 in NSKeyValueWillChange ()
#3  0x2ea03a28 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] ()
#4  0x2ea601c0 in _NSSetIntValueAndNotify ()
#5  0x2dcfa630 in -[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish] ()
#6  0x2dd56a24 in __59-[__NSCFLocalSessionBridge task:didFinishLoadingWithError:]_block_invoke ()
#7  0x2dd56770 in -[__NSCFLocalSessionBridge task:didFinishLoadingWithError:] ()
#8  0x2dd54e68 in __64-[__NSCFLocalSessionBridge initWithConfiguration:session:queue:]_block_invoke ()
#9  0x2dd72f24 in ___ZNK24ClassicConnectionSession28_connection_didFinishLoadingEP16_CFURLConnection_block_invoke ()
#10 0x38d65d52 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#11 0x38d6acbc in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#12 0x38d67c6e in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#13 0x38d6b5f0 in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#14 0x38d6b8dc in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#15 0x38e96c16 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#16 0x38e96adc in start_wqthread ()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like one of your observers wasn't unregistered before it got dealloc'd. No idea what that might be without looking at your code, but I'd strongly recommend using Facebook's KVOController for your KVO needs. It handles unobserving for you, so this type of thing can't happen.

Comment: I didn't know about Facebook's KVOController, it looks interesting. The readme on github led me here : http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5305010728468480 which looks a lot like what's happening to me. Is it a bug in Apple's framework or a bad code design ?

Comment: Glad you found it – sorry I forgot to include a link. Don't know what to say about that radar link (especially without seeing any of your code), but for whatever it's worth, I've been using the KVOController since it was released and have never experienced that crash.

Comment: Any idea what block is being invoked? Is it yours?

Comment: The block being invoked is not mine. Here is a gist with my code : https://gist.github.com/ghugues/639f459e189643b54041 It is possible the bug I mentioned is the reason of the crash because my observers are removed properly before being deallocated. Besides, the NSURLSession API seems to be working with a lot of different threads. observeValueForKeyPath: is being called from at least 2 different threads that are not the ones the operation is allocated/deallocated from.